# Popular Select com XML - Lógica

Tags: javascript, xml, lógica

Olá, preciso popular um select para que eles sejam dinâmicos.
O cliente é um site de carros, ou seja, o usuário poderá agendar os carros.

o meu trabalho é de popular o select, entretanto estou tendo dificuldades porque o XML me parece mal estruturado...

Terei 4 selects
cidade, loja, marca e carro.

Ou seja, se o usuário selecionar São Paulo, mostrará apenas as lojas e os carros disponíveis em sp...

Mas, creio eu que o XML esteja mal organizado, porquê ele me retorna o nome da cidade mais de uma vez...

Segue abaixo  o código...

```
<entry>
    <g:id>109851</g:id> 
    <title>FIAT UNO 1.0 FIREFLY FLEX ATTRACTIVE 4P MANUAL</title> 
    <g:description>Nenhuma descrição encontrada.</g:description> 
    <link></link> 
    <g:image_link></g:image_link> 
    <g:availability>in stock</g:availability> 
    <g:price>34290 BRL</g:price> 
    <g:google_product_category>916</g:google_product_category> 
    <g:brand>FIAT</g:brand> 
    <g:identifier_exists>no</g:identifier_exists>
    <g:condition>used</g:condition> 
    <g:adult>no</g:adult> 
    <g:is_bundle>no</g:is_bundle> 
    <g:color>PRATA</g:color> 
    <state>Minas Gerais</state> 
    <city>Belo Horizonte</city> 
    <store>Belo Horizonte - Estoril</store> 
  </entry>
```

Em cada entry tem uma cidade, e se eu busco essa cidade com o fetch do jquery, ele me retorna todas as cidades de todas as entrys(a mesma cidade umas 100 vezes)...

O correto seria eu pedir para eles reformularem este XML? ou é possível eu me virar com ele?

//edit

o meu código

```
    $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "googleshoppingcustom.xml",
            dataType: 'xml',
            success: function(xml){
              $(xml).find('entry').find('state').each(function(i){
                var state = $(this).text();
                $('#region').append(`<option value=${state}>${state}</option>`)

)}
```

[image: Ele me retorna isto...]

**O meu real problema, não chega nem a ser essa repetição... e sim como que eu conseguiria pegar CADA marca de carro para CADA carro... estou achando o xml um pouco bagunçado...**

Comment: O xml tem cerca de cinco mil linhas... Está muito confuso pessoal?

Answer (score 0):

> Em vez de usar 2 `.find`, basta fazer assim: `$(xml).find('entry state')...` que já busca todos as tags `<state>` dentro de `<entry>`.

Você pode ir fazendo o append verificando se um `state` já foi inserido ou não, resultando em options únicos com os nomes dos Estados:

```
$.ajax({
   type: "GET",
   url: "googleshoppingcustom.xml",
   dataType: 'xml',
   success: function(xml){
      $(xml).find('entry state').each(function(i){

         var state = $(this).text();

         // verifica se já existe um option com o nome do Edtado
         if( !$('#region option[value="'+ state +'"]').length ){
            $('#region').append(`<option value='${state}'>${state}</option>`);
         }
      });
   }
});
```